# ASP.NET Definition Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble understanding what the problem is. The error that I am receiving is:

'`ASP.newevents_aspx`' does not contain a definition for '`BUSAVEInfo_Click`' and no extension method '`BUSAVEInfo_Click`' accepting a first argument of type '`ASP.newevents_aspx`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I feel like I have done everything right. Please do let me know what I am missing. I've been learning ASP.NET for a few weeks now. Thanks.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="NewEvents.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewEvents" %> 
<!-- CSS, HEAD and BODY Tags removed to compress content --!>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
          <%-- Event Name Field --%>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Event Name: " Width="100"></asp:Label> <asp:TextBox ID="Ename" runat="server" Width="408px" CssClass="auto-style2"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="Name is Required" ControlToValidate="Ename"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

          <%-- Event Description Field --%>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2"  
            runat="server"
            Text="Event Description:"
            Width="120px" 
            CssClass="auto-style1">

        </asp:Label>

            <asp:TextBox 
            ID="Escript"
            runat="server"
            Width="408px" 

            ></asp:TextBox>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" 
                runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Description is Required"
                ControlToValidate="Escript">

            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


          <%-- Event Coordinater Name Field --%>
            <asp:Label 
                ID="EventCordNm" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="Coordinater Name: ">

            </asp:Label>

            <asp:TextBox 
                ID="ECordNm"
                 runat="server"
                 CssClass="auto-style4" 
                Width="409px">

            </asp:TextBox>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" 
                runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Coordinator Name is Required"
                ControlToValidate="ECordNm">

            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <br />
            <br />

           <%-- Event Coordinater Phone Field --%>
            <asp:Label 
                ID="EventCordPn" 
                runat="server" 
                Text=" Coordinater Phone#: ">

            </asp:Label>

            <asp:TextBox 
                ID="ECordNum" 
                runat="server" 
                CssClass="auto-style5"
                 Width="368px">

            </asp:TextBox>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
                runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Phone Number is Required"
                ControlToValidate="ECordNum">

            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                runat="server" ControlToValidate="ECordNum" 
                ErrorMessage="Invalid Phone Number" 
                ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}">

            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

           <br />
           <br />

           <%-- Event Coordinater Email Field --%>
            <asp:Label 
                ID="EventCordEml"
                 runat="server" 
                Text=" Coordinater Email: ">

            </asp:Label>

            <asp:TextBox 
                ID="ECordEml" 
                runat="server"
                CssClass="auto-style6" 
                Width="375px">

            </asp:TextBox>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" 
                runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="Email is Required"
                ControlToValidate="ECordEml">

            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="ECordEml"
                ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address" 
                ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">

            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <br />
            <br />

             <%-- Event Fee Field --%>
            <asp:Label ID="EventFee"
            runat="server"
            Width="100"
            Text="Event Fee:">

            </asp:Label>

            <asp:TextBox 
            ID="EvFee"
            runat="server"
            Width="100"
            ></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="EvFee" 
                ErrorMessage="Fee is Required">

            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <asp:CompareValidator 
                ID="CompareValidator1" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="EvFee" 
                ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" 
                Operator="GreaterThan" 
                Type="Double" 
                ValueToCompare="0">Price Must be greater than 0

            </asp:CompareValidator>

            <br />

           <%-- Event Date Field --%>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3"
            runat="server"
            Width="100"
            Text="Event Date:">

            </asp:Label>


            <asp:TextBox 
            ID="EDate"
            runat="server"
            Width="90"
            ></asp:TextBox>

            <br />
            <br />
           <%-- Event Calender Field --%>
            <asp:Calendar 
                ID="Calendar1"
                runat="server"
                Align="center"
                OneDayRender="Calender1_Dayrender" 
                OnSelectionChanged="Calender1_SelectionChanged">

            </asp:Calendar>


            <br /> <br/>
        <asp:Button
            ID="BtnReturn"
            runat="server"
            Text="Return"
            PostBackUrl="default.aspx" />

        <asp:Button 
            ID="BUSaveInfo" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Save" 
            Width="100" 
            OnClick="BUSAVEInfo_Click"
            CausesValidation="false"
             />

        </div>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class NewEvents : System.Web.UI.Page {
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

public void Calender1_Dayrender(Object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e){ }

public void Calender1_SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e){
    EDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

protected void BUSaveInfo_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your capitalization. `BUSaveInfo_Click` is the name of the method, but `BUSAVEInfo_Click` is what's in the markup.

They need to match.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that; I always miss the simple stuff. Thank you :)